# functional composition of pandas' Series

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to get functional composition of pandas `Series`? To clarify the question, a `Series` is a map from its index to its values. Given two Series `s` and `t` how do I construct their composition `u` such that its index is that of s and for each `i` in `s.index` `u[i] = t[s[i]]`. I currently do the following:

```
u = pd.Series(t[s].values, index=s.index)
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `map` is for.  Just do `u = s.map(t)`.